# Why does Electrum keep creating receiving addresses?

Tags: wallet, address, electrum

Everytime I open Electrum up, a new address for receiving is generated.

Why is this happening? Is it supposed to generate so many addresses?

I have over 20 receiving address at the moment.

This seems to happen every time I start up Electrum for the first time after boot.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electrum allow you to create HD wallets that use seed to generate a near infinite amount of addresses.

All bitcoin addresses are public so it is better to use different addresses each time you receive coins for privacy reasons

Here is the official answer to your question from electrum: https://bitcoinelectrum.com/frequently-asked-questions/#why-does-electrum-give-me-a-different-address-everytime

Comment: You sir, are awesome. Thanks for providing a link to explain this. I really appreciate it. Have an upvote.